# AspectJ: List<Object> pointcut args

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void updatePeople(List<Person> people) { //DO STUFF }

}
```

I want to log the size of `people` when `updatePeople` is called by AOP.

This is my aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(void com.bla.bla.MyClass.updatePeople(List<Person>)) && args(people)")
    public void updatePeople(List<Person> people) {}

    @Before("updatePeople(people)")
    public void log(List<Person> people) {
        log(people.size());
    }

}
```

But `log` is never called. I guess `List<Person>` syntax is is not correct in the pointcut. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I changed the pointcut into this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(void com.bla.bla.MyClass.updatePeople(..)) && args(people)")
public void updatePeople(List<Person> people) {}
```